# Cordova File Transfer remove Multipart or Content-Disposition Header

Tags: cordova, multipartform-data, file-transfer, content-disposition

I managed to upload an image to my server using Cordova File Transfer plugin.

```
var img = <full path to image>
var url = <url to webservice>

var options = new FileUploadOptions(); //no specified options, using defaults
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(img, encodeURI(url), win, fail, options);

var win = function (r) {
    console.log('Successfully sent');
}
var fail = function (error) {
    console.log("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
};
```

However, my server had problems reading the image due to the extra header added by the plugin.

```
--+++++..Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.jpg"..Content-Type: image/jpeg....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me awhile to figure this but this is the way I removed the Multipart Header. Here's the solution/work around.

Open: \platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\filetransfer\FileTransfer.java

Look for:

```
sendStream.write(beforeDataBytes);
totalBytes += beforeDataBytes.length;
```

Comment away or delete these 2 lines. They are the code that adds the multipart header.

Also remove:

```
sendStream.write(tailParamsBytes);
totalBytes += tailParamsBytes.length;
```

This code adds a tail for the multipart header.

I have done a MD5 checksum check and they are of the same now.

Answer (score 0):

Please add headers to options

```
var headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};
options.headers = headers;
```

Just refer the [example](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#example-with-upload-headers-and-progress-events-android-and-ios-only) from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a 'Content-Type' in Headers.

> headers: A map of header name/header values. Use an array to specify more than one value. On iOS, FireOS, and Android, if a header named Content-Type is present, multipart form data will NOT be used. (Object)

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#example-with-upload-headers-and-progress-events-android-and-ios-only

Comment: I do not want any Multipart form data nor any Content-Type value at all. I have looked through the code in FileTransfer.java and it does not seem to have any option for it to be turned off entirely. 
Although not elegant, but a simple commenting of 4 lines does the job, without any changes to my webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code:

```
boolean multipartFormUpload = (headers == null) || !headers.has("Content-Type");
if (multipartFormUpload) {
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY);
}
```

You can find it is easy to disable the multipart header by setting a dummy header option in your javascript:

```
options.headers = {"Content-Type":"dummy"}; // set it to something to avoid the plug-in append the header
```