# Upload to s3 end with extra content in file

Tags: android, amazon-s3, ionic-framework

I am developing an Android app using Ionic and the [ngCordova File Transfer plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) to upload files to Amazon S3. However, uploaded files appear to have extra content, like `Content-Disposition...` as seen below:

```
--+++++
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG_20150817_205738_1439818078787.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
<ORIGINAL FILE CONTENT GOES HERE>
--+++++--
```

My code is as follows:

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(signedPutUrl, fileUrl, {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: fileName,
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    chunkedMode: false,
    httpMethod: 'PUT',
    encodeURI: false,
    params: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    }
}, true)
```

Why is this the case and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova File Transfer remove Multipart or Content-Disposition Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175836/cordova-file-transfer-remove-multipart-or-content-disposition-header)

Comment: The file transfer plugin seems broken to me.  A review of the source code suggests it has no way of doing a simple `PUT` request with raw binary data as S3 expects.  That, or it isn't the right choice of tool for an S3 PUT.

Comment: Looks scary to me to modify these source code. But I did try to modify the source code, but no lucky. Seems I have to find another way to work out.